# Get into iPhone with netcat

Tags: macos, tcp, terminal, netcat

I wanted get in to my iPhone with terminal so I did some research, then I found out that it is using tcp ok port 62078.

When I run command:

```
nc iphoneIP 62078
```

It doesn’t show any error message so I supposed the command ran fine but nothing was returned.

Can anyone tell me a way to use this command correctly or perhaps accomplish the same result with a different command?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what application that is listening on port 62078? Quick google search https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4992565. Also, If you want to get in you should run ssh/telnet, but I do not know if it is possible.

Comment: @FormerNcp I don’t understand the question “what application that is listening on port 62078”. I am just trying to connect to my iPhone from terminal just like how we can connect to computers using ssh command.

Comment: When you connect to a computer through ssh there is a ssh-server that listens on port 22. So you need an application running on the iphone that accepts ssh to connect to it using ssh. If there is a http-server on port 62078 you will not be able to ssh to port 62078.